# No consigo enviar datos desde el el frontend Angular a un Backend Laravel

Tags: laravel, angular, backend, servicio, frontend

Buenas tardes a tod@s.

Me he topado con este problema y no se donde esta el error. Tengo un servicio en el frontend que toma datos recogidos desde un formulario y los envía al back. No se que hago mal pero los datos no llegan al back end.

**user-register.component.ts :**

```
    onSubmit(form:any){
    
    console.log(this.user);
    console.log(this.user.phone_number);
 
    this._userService.register(this.user).subscribe({
      next: (response) =>{
         console.log(response);
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      complete: () => console.info('complete') 
    });
  }
```

**user.service.ts :**

```
register(user:any): Observable<any>{
        let json = JSON.stringify(user);
        let params = 'json='+json;
        
        let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-ulrencoded');
        
        return this._http.post(this.url + 'user/register', params, {headers: headers});
    }
```

**UserController.php  :**

```
//metodo de registro de usuario
    public function register(Request $request) {
        
        //recoger datos de usuario por post Y Decodificar datos JSON
        $json = $request->input('json', null);
        $params = json_decode($json);
        $params_array = json_decode($json, true);
        
        
        if(!empty($params) && !empty($params_array)) {
           
            $params_array = array_map('trim', $params_array);

            //validar datos
            $validate = \Validator::make($params_array, [
                        'name' => 'required|alpha',
                        'surname' => 'required|alpha',
                        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users', //comprobar si existe usuario
                        'password' => 'required',

            ]);

            if ($validate->fails()) {
                //validacion fallida
                $data = array(
                    'status' => 'error',
                    'code' => 400,
                    'message' => 'El usuario no se ha creado correctamente',
                    'error' => $validate->errors()
                );
            } else {
                //validación pasada correctamente
          
                //cifrar la contraseña
                $pwd = hash('sha256', $params->password);
                                
                //crear usuario
                $user = new User();
                $user->name = $params_array['name'];
                $user->surname = $params_array['surname'];
                $user->email = $params_array['email'];
                $user->password = $pwd;
                $user->role = 'ROLE_USER';
                
                //guardar el usuario
                $user->save();

                $data = array(
                    'status' => 'success',
                    'code' => 200,
                    'message' => 'El usuario se ha creado correctamente',
                    'user' => $user
                );
            }
        } else {
            $data = array(
                    'status' => 'error',
                    'code' => 400,
                    'message' => 'Los datos enviados no son correctos',
                );
        }

        return response()->json($data, $data['code']);  
    }
```

El tema es que no recibo nada el $request. Y salta directamente el error 400. Diciendo que los datos nos son validos.
He comprobado en consola y los datos llegan al servicio y se almacenan en el params. pero cuando hago un return de $request o de $json, para comprobar los datos, estos están vacíos.

He probado coger el json del servicio y enviarlo por Postman al controlador, y funciona perfectamente, se almacena correctamente en la base de datos.

**CORS**
He intentado añadir los CORS tanto en **index.php** como en **app.js** :
index

```
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method ,  Authorization");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    header("Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    if($method == "OPTIONS") {
       die();
    }
```

app.js

```
    // Configurar cabeceras y cors
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    next();
    });
```

De ninguna manera me funcionó.
Alguna idea.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Ese 404 te dice que la ruta no se encuentra. Verifica la ruta que te genera el frontend y la ruta que usas en postman, quizás falte un "`/`" Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. He comprobado la ruta y es correcta, exactamente la misma de postaman. El tema esq no llega nada al back end. por eso salta directamente a que los datos enviados no son correctos.

Comment: En ese caso, estás utilizando mal los Http Status, un 404 se utiliza cuando algo no se ha encontrado. Podrías usar 400 como un bad request. Con lo que dices, estás enviando mal el paquete json, compara lo que envías en el postman y lo que fue enviado desde el frontend (click derecho, inspeccionar elemento y vas a la pestaña Network, o sencillamente F12 y pestaña network, ahí verás el payload o body del request).

Comment: Gracias fredyfx. Tienes razón el 404 lleva a confusión, ya lo cambie por 400. he visto el network me aparece esto: Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: Ahora tienes que habilitar el CORS en tu server :) sigue avanzando, vas por buen camino :D

Comment: Ahí ya estoy perdido jeje. tenia el CORS habilitado pero era con una version antigua de angular, ahora estoy rehaciendo el proyecto con angular 15, pero ya no me vale como estaba.  lo tenia en el index.php. Luego lo intente en resources/js/app.js pero nada. y ahora estoy perdido. @fredyfx